# SKSpriteNode not affected by Gravity Behaviour when i add programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

I am new to Gaming in Swift.

I am trying to make the Gravity point at the centre of the screen and all other objects (SKSpriteNode) will be attracted towards the centre of the screen.

I successfully created Gravity point at the centre.

The issue is,

**1**.

> I added an image to the Scene by **dragging and droping the image** in
>   `.sks` file. That image is getting attracted towards my gravity point.
>   (Image moves towards the gravity point and after that it moves out of
>   screen fastly, I don't know why it is not staying at the gravity
>   point)

**2**.

> I added another image by programmatically
>
> The image was created successfully but not getting attracted towards
>   the gravity point.

```
    let player1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dot")
    player1.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 4, y: size.height / 4)
    player1.setScale(0.05) 
    player1.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    player1.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    player1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    addChild(player1)
```

Why it is getting attracted when i add by drag and drop and not attracted when i add by programmatically ?

Please point out what mistake i am doing. Thanks for the time. (:

Comment: You have to initialize physics body like this: player1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 
    (player1.size.width/2))